# Cleanup of /tmp

Tags: linux, tmp

What mechanism controls how often/when the /tmp directory is cleaned up. If there is such built-in mechanism at all or do I need to resort to a custom cron?

I'd appreciate either a specific command/tool or if you just point me to where I can find the appropriate documentation.

I am using Ubuntu 10.04 server if it matters.

Comment: There is no built-in mechanism. Have a look at this http://serverfault.com/questions/143852/does-ubuntu-server-have-any-sort-of-cron-job-to-automatically-clear-tmp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Ubuntu, install tmpreaper.

```
apt-get install tmpreaper
```

Comment: Thank you. tmpreaper tool is exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 1):

[tmpwatch](https://fedorahosted.org/tmpwatch/) can be used to clean up `/tmp`.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can mount it in in swap/ramdisk (google for how to set that up) Solaris does this by default, cleans up with every reboot. :-) I've done it with Linux, it can be very nice, and makes /tmp nice and fast.

Personally, I would only delete stuff from /tmp that is older than the last reboot, or that I know is safe, lots of things have working data in /tmp, and it may we be from just after boot (I don't know that for sure, but I would be cautious, granted, worst case, reboot and you are fixed).

Answer (score 1):

For long uptimes, `tmpreaper` is the way to go.

Ubuntu cleans `/tmp` at each boot. If you reboot, files may be deleted that you may have intended to keep based on thresholds supplied to `tmpreaper`. You can control boot-time `/tmp` cleaning using the `TMPTIME` variable.

From [`man rcS`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/en/man5/rcS.5.html):

> TMPTIME
>   On boot the files in /tmp will be deleted if their modification time is more than TMPTIME days ago. A value of 0 means that files are removed regardless of age. If you don't want the system to clean /tmp then set TMPTIME to a negative value (e.g., -1) or to the word infinite.