# What is the most efficient way to handle /tmp and disk quotas on Linux

Tags: linux, quota, tmp

I'm running a VPS with a webserver (Apache+PHP), a database (MySQL) and smtp server (Exim). OS: Debian Lenny. RAM: 512MB. Using (quota](http://packages.debian.org/lenny/quota).

At the moment, I've `/tmp` mounted as tmpfs. This is not ideal, as I've only 512MB RAM and thus, `/tmp` is only 256MB. I've decided to create a 1GB ext3 partition file (or whatever it's called) on `/var/tmpdisk`. (the decision on using ext3 was made after reading [Askubuntu.com: Good filesystem for /tmp?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1637/good-filesystem-for-tmp/1655#1655))

For keeping /tmp clean while running, I've found tmpreaper: [serverfault.com: Cleanup of /tmp](https://serverfault.com/q/177093/51929)

**What would be recommended for quickly wiping `/var/tmpdisk`, while retaining the quota settings?**

Currently, I'm thinking of doing the following on startup (`/etc/rc.local`?):

1. Check for the existence of `/var/tmpdisk`. if it does not exist, run `dd if=/dev/zero of=/var/tmpdisk bs=1K count=1000000`
2. Create the ext3 filesystem in `/var/tmpdisk`. This was the fastest way for me on clearing the "disk". Command: `mkfs.ext3 -F /var/tmpdisk`
3. Mount it on `/tmp`: `mount -t ext3 -o loop,rw,nodev,noexec,nosuid,quota /var/tmpdisk /tmp`

In this draft, I have not added a way for keeping the quota settings. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most of my requirements have already been available in Debian.

By default, `/etc/default/rcS` sets environment variable `TMPTIME=0`.

`$ man rcS`:

> TMPTIME
>
> > On  boot  the files in /tmp will be deleted if their modification time is more than TMPTIME days ago.  **A value of 0 means that files are removed regardless of age**.  If you don't want the system to clean /tmp then set TMPTIME to a negative value (e.g., -1) or to the word infinite.

Looking in `/lib/init/bootclean.sh`, I found out that the quota file './aquota.user`(owned by root) is excluded from removing. Conclusion: quota settings will persist during reboots and`TMPTIME=0`can safely be set in`/etc/default/rcS`.

To keep `/tmp` clean while running, I installed `tmpreaper`.
To activate it, `SHOWWARNING=true` should be commented. Furthermore, `TMPREAPER_TIME=7d` should be uncommented in order to clean files older than 7 days.

A 1GB temp disk was created and formatted ext3 with:

```
# dd if=/dev/zero of=/var/tmpdisk bs=1K count=1000000
# mkfs.ext3 -F /var/tmpdisk
```

Mounting it at boot-time required a change in `/etc/fstab`:

```
# /var/tmpdisk /tmp ext3 loop,rw,nosuid,noexec,nodev,quota 0 0
```

Since `/var/tmpdisk` is not a real device, it should be mounted as loop device, hence `loop`. `nosuid,noexec,nodev` have been added as a layer of security to prevent common exploit kits from abusing `/tmp`. Finally, `quota` enables quota for the disk.

After modifying `/etc/fstab`, I ran `mount -a` to mount the new `/tmp` disk. Since `/tmp` should be world-writable, and users should not be able to delete files they do not own, the directory permissions should be changed too:

```
# chmod 1777 /tmp
```

Activate quotas:

```
# quotacheck /tmp
# quotaon /tmp
```

Now `/tmp` fully suits my needs with quotas activated and auto-cleaning junk files. The only thing I have to do is adding quotas for each user by running `edquota username`.